# Querying 3D Model in Google Earth Similar To Polygons

Tags: google-earth

Right now I have polygons that represent a water surface in case of a flood event. Using polygons is becoming untenable, so I would like to pursue alternatives.  One alternative I thought of is generating a collada 3D model instead.  Before I go down that route, I wanted to know if it was possible to be able to query the 3D model in Google Earth.  I know you can put metadata per polygon and query that polygon directly in Google Earth by clicking on it, but I would like to do that with a 3D model.

Is that possible?

It's fine if it's data per triangle, but if it was somehow possible to get the interpolated value at the click position that would be great as well.